# How to make multiple UI updates sequentially?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

The network communication ended and received a response. Then, what is an efficient way to update UI elements one by one without updating multiple UI elements at the same time?

Comment: This is unclear. Do you have multiple network requests and you need to update respective the UI elements as the individual network responses come in? Or do you have a network response with multiple pieces of information and you want to simply add some delays to the updates so they appear to happen consecutively to achieve a certain visual effect? A little more information about the nature of the UI elements would be helpful, too (e.g. rows in `UITableView`, various outlets in a given storyboard scene, etc.). Feel free to edit your question with the additional details.

Answer (score 0):

UI updation should be done on main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update your UI
    });
```